# C# Process.Start: how to read output?

Tags: c#, process, output

I tried all the solutions to the other questions, but none of them worked. I also tried "call filename.exe>log.txt" in CMD, but it didn't work. I'd appreciate it if you could help me with this.

I am a non-English-speaking student, so the expression may be strange. I'd appreciate your understanding.

```
using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = ProcessPath;
                    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(ProcessPath);
                    process.Start();

                    while (process.HasExited)
                    {
                        TextBox1.AppendText(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()+"\r\n");
                    }

                    process.WaitForExit();
                }
```

Comment: [How do I get output from a command to appear in a control on a Form in real-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682585/7444103) -- Read the notes about the `SynchronizingObject` property.

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is not  a helpful problem description!

Comment: `while (process.HasExited)` is an endless loop. The state can't change to false anymore. Instead of this you can `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` This is a blocking call, it waits until the process has finished. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=net-5.0)

Comment: I don't excactly understand what output you mean? Do you want to display the text of a generated file called log.txt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capture the standard output/error of a Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633653/how-to-capture-the-standard-output-error-of-a-process) and [C# process hanging due to StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() and StandardError.ReadToEnd()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214380/c-sharp-process-hanging-due-to-standardoutput-readtoend-and-standarderror-read) and [StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160187/standardoutput-readtoend-hangs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are checking for `process.HasExited` in a while loop.
This, of course will be false by default, and then your code will just skip this. That is why I suggest using an asynchronous method or an event-based aproach.

If you choose asynchronous, you can do this:

```cs
using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
{
    errors = await process.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();
    results = await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

here, `psi` is an instance of `ProcessStartInfo`.
You set them after creating the process, but you can create an object and pass that in the constructor.

If you cannot make it asynchronous, you can do:

```cs
using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
{
    errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync().Result;
    results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync().Result;
}
```

Comment: Thank u! I'll try this method!

Answer (score 1):

Use events and set them before start:

```cs
process.ErrorDataReceived += (sendingProcess, errorLine) => error.AppendLine(errorLine.Data);
process.OutputDataReceived += (sendingProcess, dataLine) => SetLog(dataLine.Data);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it!